# Calling Word method Application.ComAddins crashes after downgrading from Office 2013 to Office 2010

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, com, ms-office

Some of our clients downgraded from Office 2013 to Office 2010.

After doing that if you call the Application property ComAddins you get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8002801D): Library not registered. (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.get_COMAddIns()
   at our own code
```

We have tried to reinstall Office doing different cleanings to no avail. Any idea on what's wrong on the registry or how to fix it?

Can we find which registration is wrong and fix it somehow?

**EDIT:**

This is a sample that works on normal machines and fails on downgraded ones:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordCorruptionTester
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application application = null;
            try
            {
                application = new Application();
                COMAddIns addins = application.COMAddIns;
                File.WriteAllText(@"c:\appAgn\office.txt", "OK");
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(addins);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
            }
            catch
            {
                File.WriteAllText(@"c:\appAgn\office.txt", "CORRUPTO");
                if (application != null)
                {
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CONTINUATION:**

Following some really valid comments that's the new information gathered:

*@Dirk Vollmar*: Executing winword /r makes no difference.

*@TnTinMn*: long story short. Following your advice I found no issues but I 
saw that the file pointed by the interface was winword.olb so I re-registered it with `"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSWORD.OLB""` as the error was about Library not registered. After doing this the error message changed to:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040155): Interface not registered (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040155)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass.get_COMAddIns()
   at our own code
```

Investigating a bit more I decompiled our own code that calls the get_COMAddIns and I found embedded the ID of the interface called: "000C0339-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"

[image]

Comment: How are you declaring the application Object?  Is its type `Word.Application` or `Word.ApplicationClass`?  I suspect that it is the "Class" type and that the code was compiled to use the Office PIA's in the GAC instead of embedding the interop types.

Comment: @TnTinMn: I added some proof of concept, we do not use the ApplicationClass :\

Comment: Just so we have all the information, are the Word references to set to Embedded or are you referencing the PIA's.    In the Solution Explorer, right-click the `Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and select properties.  What is the value for "Embed Interop Types"?

Comment: Did you build against the 2013 type library? Or, is the interop assembly built against 2013 and not 2010? Use Process Monitor to find out which type library is being looked for in the registry. Make sure it is there. Look up the Word.Application clsid on the machine and from there look at the type library then look up the type library and especially the path to it.

Comment: @TnTinMn: all the Word references are embedded.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson: how can I differentiate the call made in the registry? Usually there are tons of calls to the registry and lots of them fail. I'll try what you say about following the registrations.

Comment: Just a reminder, It works fine in Office 2013 and 2010 installations, it fails only if we downgrade from 2013 to 2010.

Comment: Well, set a break point in your debugger. Clear out all the chatter before that and make sure you are only looking at your process. Shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Just a guess, but check registry key `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\Interface\{00020970-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\TypeLib`.  Note "Version" listed there.  Copy the GUID lvalue in the "Default" field.  Search for that GUID in the Keys; it should be at `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{the GUID value}.    Inspect the sub key `Version Number\0\Win32`; look a the file path listed in the "Default" field.  That path may be pointing to the 2013 type library.

Comment: The problem seems to be an incorrect registration. Have you tried running `winword.exe /r` to reregister all Word components in the Registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue this way (looks like an MS Office installer bug when downgrading from Office 2013 to Office 2010 that affects office automation):

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSWORD.OLB""

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>regtlibv12.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Office14\MSO.DLL""
```

This registrations leave the system working again.